# Splitting a field value in MySQL using a regex delimiter?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to split a string in MySQL using a regex delimiter. Is there any way this could be done?

I found this blog post explaining how to implement a simple split string function:
[mysql split string function](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

However, i have to split my string by two alternative characters, so i would want to use this regex: [-,] to separate the string.

Here is an example of the table i have and what i want to achieve:

```
| id | range |
|----|-------|
|  1 | 2,3,5 |
|  2 | 1-4   |
|  3 | 2     |
```

What i want to do is finding the min and max values of each "range"-field.
So, i would like to get:

Row 1: 2 and 5
Row 2: 1 and 4
Row 3: 2

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please show us an example of what you want to do?

Comment: OK, i added an example - this shows more detailed what i want to achieve with this.

Comment: I would go for one more table to store each range, its not a good idea to store several data in one col. However let me think about your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your table name is named `data` and the values in `range` are sorted from the minimum to the maximum, would it be ok?

```
SELECT id, 
(0 + data.range) AS min,
GREATEST(
  0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(data.range, ',', -1),
  0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(data.range, '-', -1)
) AS max
FROM `data`
```

However you should really think about creating a new table for the ranges as Boris suggested it, it would be cleaner if you can.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working! Although i do not understand it completely. Could you point out why you use GREATEST to select the one of the both results we get from the SUBSTRING_INDEX functions?

Comment: Right it's useless to use GREATEST for the minimum, I updated the query, you just need to use the '+ 0' to parse 'range' as an interger.